# Caching proxy for yum and debian repositories

Tags: proxy, yum, cache, apt

1. Does a caching proxy for yum exist, similar to approx for Debian repositories?
2. Is there a way to have reprepro behave the same as approx? I have heard that approx was not as stable; besides, I would prefer the use of reprepro so that I could use my existing web server to serve the repository.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing will probably be [mrepo](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/mrepo/).  It's run out of band from Yum itself, though.  You'd set up local mirrors of your favorite yum repos with mrepo and point your yum clients to that instead.  It handles apt repos also, if that's of any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

There is also http://pulpproject.org that does similar things as mrepo. Currently it only works for yum, but folks are working hard adding support for other technologies. It supports Puppet today (2014) and the core was refactored so patches for Debian support are possible.